# How to move cursor to the end of auto completed words after auto completion in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am writing a web page in HTML and CSS. I want to know how I can move the cursor (caret) out of the ending double (or single) quote `"` after auto completion. I have searched many places, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Just type the quote - it will not add another quote to the document but move past it.

Answer (score 0):

Search for **"Editor: Accept Suggestion On Enter"** in the settings search bar.

and Ensure that the option is set to "**on**" or "**smart**" (default). If it's set to "**off**," it may prevent the cursor from moving to the end of the word after auto-completion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was set to on. I also tried smart. Is there a way to move the cursor after the double quote or after the semi-colon (the end of the line) after autocompletioin?